# OS.File.DirectoryIterator timeout in Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I have a situation where I am iterating over a directory of files in Firefox with something like the following:

```
let iterator = OS.File.DirectoryIterator(dir);
let itPromise = iterator.forEach(entry){
return OS.File.read(entry.path).then(array => {
 return anotherPromise(array).then (
.
.
.
 }
});

return itPromise.then( function () {
//DO stuff after iterator is completely done
});
```

It seems like this iterator promise sometimes times out and never makes it to the //Do stuff after iterator line.
If I am doing this for a small number of files, it seems to work fine - but if my iterator seems to take more than say, a minute (or some unknown magic number), the promise never returns. Is firefox doing something to shut down my OS.File iterator?

I read in a bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1279389

that there is a osfile.reset_worker_delay preference, but I don't seem to be able to find that in Firefox 47, or any of the developer versions I downloaded.

Is that what is causing my problem - the iterator takes too long, and thus firefox wont skip to the next part?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `DirectoryIterator`.

1. Normally, the only case in which something like a timeout should ever happen is if your code is executed during shutdown. Is this the case?
2. Preference `osfile.reset_worker_delay` is available only on Nightly or Developer Edition. Yes, it's quite possible that there is a bug with this pref. If you could provide a minimal sample that we could reproduce, that would be very helpful. To test on your side, you could see what happens if you set the value to a very high number (say `1000000`).

Comment: Ive had to create a work-around and restructure my code. If I get a chance, I can see if I can make a minimal test case, but it might not be for a bit.